# version `GLIBC_2.25' not found when trying to use argon2 hash function javascript/typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker

I am trying to use the `hash` function from the `argon2` JavaScript package, but I am getting the following error:

```js
Error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.25' not found (required by /app/node_modules/argon2/lib/binding/napi-v3/argon2.node)
     at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1144:18)
     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:93:18)
     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/argon2/argon2.js:9:56)
     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12) {
   code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
 }
 [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Here is the my code that is erroring out:

```
import { hash } from "argon2";
(async () {
  const hashedPassword = await hash(password);
})();
```

I did find this [discussion on askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1021420/glibc-2-25-not-found-on-ubuntu-windows-subsystem-for-linux), but the steps illustrated there don't really apply to me. The error might be coming from the fact that I am using `docker`...

Here is the `dockerfile` for my server (where the erroring code lives):

```
FROM node:14

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json .

RUN npm i

COPY . .

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

Here is the `.dockerignore` file:

```
/node_modules
/Dockerfile
```

And here is my `docker-compose.yaml` file (the 'server' service is the one we are concerned with):

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    ports:
      - 3308:3306
    environment:
       ***
  redis:
    image: redis
    command: "redis-server --requirepass secret"
  server:
   build: ./server
   ports: 
    - "4000:80"
   volumes:
     - ./server:/app
     - /app/node_modules
     - /app/dist
   environment:
       ***
```

I haven't displayed my environment variables for obvious reasons.

Thank you for any help and feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert into in your DockerFile this line after run npm i:

RUN npm install argon2 --build-from-source